I have a P0456 very small evaporator emission leak
I do not know which area has a small leak yet, but I can tell my car is feeling the effects because when I drive, it takes a few seconds to accelerate, I am worried. Will I be okay driving it until I get paid on Friday?  Please help. I know nothing about cars. It’s a 2014 dodge avenger.

Driving with a small evap leak will not harm your vehicle. Try checking your gas cap, and if it is loose, tighten it.
It's unlikely that an evap leak would cause hesitation when you accelerate. Check for other codes and pending codes if possible.
